# How can I stop row of moving images when one reaches a certain point? (Slot reels)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a slot machine reel and I want my slots to stop at define point. I got the reel movement that looks nice but I am not sure how to stop it correctly. Currently I am compeering if image is at a define point but because it is moving it isn't exactly precise.

Here is my code:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (canSpin)
            SpinReall();

        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)))
        {

            if (!canSpin)
                canSpin = true;
            else
                canStop = true;

        }

    }

    public void SpinReall()
    {

        foreach (RectTransform slot in slots)
        {

            Vector3 newPoss = new Vector3(0, slot.localPosition.y - scrollSpeed);
            slot.localPosition = newPoss;
            if (slot.localPosition.y <= bottomBorder)
            {
                Vector3 currentPosition = slot.transform.localPosition;
                currentPosition.y = slot.localPosition.y + offsetPosition;
                slot.transform.localPosition = currentPosition;
            }

            if (canStop)
            {
                if (slots[stopIndex].transform.localPosition.y == stopPoss.localPosition.y)
                {

                    canSpin = false;
                    canStop = false;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about considering using `Mathf.Lerp` ?

Using Lerp to move object will never move beyond the end value.

Example (move targetValue from 1f to 10f in 5 seconds)

```
float timeElapsed;
float lerpDuration = 5f;
float startValue = 1f;
float endValue = 10f;
float targetValue;
void Update()
{
  if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
  {
    targetValue = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
  }
}
```

References:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html
- https://gamedevbeginner.com/the-right-way-to-lerp-in-unity-with-examples/

Comment: Not sure if that would work because my objects kind of wrap around so they need to pass a set point a few times and then when I press stop btn or time runs out it should stop

Comment: @Ivan You can use a bool variable to control moving/stop. And if you want to restart moving with new start/end/duration value, just  set `startValue` ,`endValue`,  `lerpDuration` to the new value you want before restart moving.